# Mysql - Find out which Database a particular table is present

Tags: mysql5

How would I find out which Database a particular table is present in MySql ?

```
Mysql version is 
+----------------------+
| version()            |
+----------------------+
| 5.1.35-community-log | 
+----------------------+
```

As I am having around 25 DB on an instance, I just want to find which database a particular table is present?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mysql> select * from information_schema.tables where table_name='foo'\G
```

Answer (score 0):

Following query will provides the DB name.

```
select TABLE_SCHEMA from TABLES WHERE  TABLE_NAME like '%yourtablename%'\G;
```